# How to add Search Bar in persistent bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, searchbar

[image]

I've to create bottom menu like above image. Is there any way to create bottom menu with search bar. the search bar view is static.

Help me creating view like this in flutter.

Comment: could you include your BottomNavigationBar code?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the search field to the BottomNavigationBarItem icon parameter

```
         bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.car_crash),
                label: 'Car',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: TextField(), label: "search")
            ],
          )
```